Best way to call handlers with almost same signature

public class Config {
    static Dictionary<int, IHandler handler> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, IHandler>() {
        { 0, new Handler() },
        { 1, new Handler() },
        { 2, new SecondHandler() }
    };

    public static IHandler Get(int id) { return dictionary[id].handler; }
}

interface IHandler {
    void Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data);
}

class Handler : IHandler {
    public void Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data) {
        ...
    }
}

interface IHandlerSecond {
    void Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, IConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data);
}

class SecondHandler : Handler, IHandlerSecond {
    public void Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, IConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data) {
        base.Execute(sqlConnection, connection, transaction);
        ...
    }
}

void Main(IConnect connect) {
    // Some code

    var handler = Config.Get(num);
    if(handler is IHandlerSecond) {
        (handler as IHandlerSecond).Execute(connect, iconnection, transaction, data);
    } 
    else if (handler is IHandler) {
        (handler as IHandler).Execute(connect, transaction, data);
    }
}

So base signature looks like
    void Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data);

but one handler accepts one more parameter and I trying to find best way to do this.
My best idea was to just make another interface and check for type in main function, but it's looks kinda messy

There is no such thing as "almost the same" it's DIFFERENT signature

I see 2 solutions to your problem:
Implement common interface
A solution to your issue would be to make IHandler extend IHandlerSecond.
This way you only have to check if handler implements IHandlerSecond (which automatically implements IHandler.
Because if you have all the data for IHandlerSecond, you can always also invoke IHandler because it requires a subset of the arguments.
The final interface would look something like this:
interface IHandler : IHandlerSecond {
    void Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data);

    void IHandlerSecond.Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, IConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data)
    {
        Execute(sqlConnection, transaction, data);
    }
}

Note how in this example the IHandlerSecond interface is auto-implemented to redirect to the IHandler method. This way you do not have to implement that method in each extending class.
Use abstract class
A different solution is to rely on a single interface and create an abstract base class that abstracts away some of the logic. In that case I would get rid of IHandler because it requires the least amount of parameters.
Keep IHandlerSecond and make an abstract class like this:
abstract class HandlerBase : IHandlerSecond
{
    public void Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, IConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data)
    {
        Execute(sqlConnection, transaction, data);
    }

    protected abstract void Execute(SqlConnection sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction, List data);
}


Or basically just use IHandlerSecond only and ignore IConnection parameter when is not needed
